# AngularJS Landing Page + AdminDashboard Implementation/Concept

Tags: html, angularjs, concept

I have a sample Admin Dashboard and along with that I need to create a Landing Page aside from Admin Dashboard. So, basically there will be an Admin Dashboard App and a Landing Page App.

I am confuse right now on how to create a Landing Page.

- Do I need to create a new separate `ng-app`?
- or I will just combine the two of them in one project folder `ng-app`?

I am also thinking that it might be a good option to have button(can only see by authorized accounts) to redirect to Admin Dashboard if the logged in user is a Admin or has the rights to access the Admin Dashboard.

I hope somebody can provide me a good idea/concept of Landing Page + Admin Dashboard.

Comment: you can set different routes and make then accessible on different routes... like /home = landing page and /admin = admin panel... since its just a single landing page...would be better to just combine it..

Comment: but I see issues there, such as including of js files and css files, I think?

Comment: thr won't be any issue... if you like you can use lazyloader module to dynamically load those files...

Comment: okay thanks again. I will try it on standard procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152995/discussion-between-himanshu-bansal-and-marksmanship).